# shorten coldfusion namespaces for components

Tags: oop, coldfusion, namespaces, components

i am making an object-oriented app in coldfusion, and so i have really broken down the code. so, i have really long namespaces for my components; for example:

folder1.folder2.plugin1.datatypes.Object

i seem to be repeating a lot of stuff, but at the same time, some of these things are acting like "modules".  what i mean by this is that "folder2" in the example really contains, for lack of a better term, "stand-alone" components/applications (think of them like plugins).  so, aside from them calling other plugins' resources, they act on their own.  but, due to the folder structure, i still have to refer to them all as folder1.folder2.... and so on.

so, let us assume that the "folder1.folder2." could change on a whim.  (this will not happen, but since "plugin1" would define a stand-alone component, it does not care what "folder1" or "folder2" contains, if they even exist).

when i am writing code within the plugin, is there anyway i can shorten the namespace string; is there such a thing as "relative" namespaceing, just like using relative href links?

such a thing would save me a lot of time, but would also help ensure these things are more stand-alone as they would not be tied to their encapsulating folder structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ColdFusion mappings, specifically per-application mappings in Application.cfc.

You do this in Application.cfc

```
<cfset this.mappings["/com"] = expandPath("folder1/folder2/plugin1") />
```

The you could reference components by doing com.datatypes.object.

Cannot recall when per-app mappings came about, but its been there for a few releases.

Comment: CF8 I believe, when per-app mappings came out.

Comment: Also, the text in the expandPath() would be changed depending on where the files actually reside.

Comment: although this is extremely helpful (as there would only be one place that has the "folder1/folder2/..." mapping) it would still require hard-coding this path somewhere.

Comment: You could add an Application.cfc file in the plugin folder and use: this.mappings["/com"] = expandPath("./")

Of course then you have the issue of having to 'include' the main Application.cfc, its been done before, not easy, not extremely difficult either.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to consider dependency injection such as WireBox. This would allow you to have a single configuration file with the full paths and allow you to use an alias to obtain your models. In fact, you can even have wire box scan locations so you don't have to list every object you create.

WireBox was extracted from the amazing ColdBox framework. It is available independently of the ColdBox framework and should be somewhat simple to introduce into your application.

There is a helpful Google Group for ColdOx (and related boxes), ColdBox connection meetings that are recorded and other types of training available for WireBox.

I can not imagine building sophisticated OO without dependency injection. Well worth the effort to learn and implement.